# how to enter $email into mailto

Tags: php, html, mysql, mailto

i created a table to view user details where all the detils would be retrieved from the database. i want to set the retrieved emal address as a link so it could open in the default email application. this code here works but in the **To: textbox [default email app],** the email address is not correctly displayed i want to know **how to enter $email into mailto** i would request someone to pls provide me some help

```
if($query === false)
                                {
                                    throw new Exception(mysql_error($conn));
                                }
                                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                                {
                                    $tea_id=$row['tea_id'];
                                    $fname=$row['fname'];
                                    $lname=$row['lname'];

                                    $email=$row['email'];

                                     $username = $row['username'];
                        ?>
                <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $row['tea_id'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['fname'] ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $row['lname'] ?></td>

                    <td>

                           <?php 

                           // echo $row['email']
                           echo ('<a href="mailto:****">' . $email . '</a>')


                        ?>

                           </td>
```

[---------------------------------------CLICK HERE TO VIEW CODE-----------------------------------](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koZev.png)

Comment: Dont post codes as images

Comment: using mailto is a great way to get more spam

Comment: @rtfm then what would u suggest

Comment: a form that sends mail  is kind of standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td>
echo "<a href='mailto:".$email."?Subject=Contact%20Form&body=This is content' target="_top">".$email."</a>";
</td>
```

Comment: **i tried to add this line to the code i get errors can u pls help** `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span>`

Comment: have imported required files?

Comment: check this https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_glyphs&stacked=h

Answer (score 1):

The email line should be :

```
echo '<a href="mailto:' . $email . '">' . $email . '</a>'
```

With a subject :

```
echo '<a href="mailto:' . $email . '?subject=' . $subject . '">' . $email . '</a>'
```

and ofcourse you should set the `$subject` variable first.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use concatenation to join the mailto statement and the email variable from the database.

```
echo '<a href = "mailto:' . $your_email .'" . '</a>'
```